# Adding Additional Properties to the UIView in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to add custom properties to the `UIView` so I can use them among all `UIView` objects *and* all the `UIView`'s subclasses, like `UIImageView`, `UISlider` ... etc

I've tried to use Category to do so, but it turns out I can't use instance variables in the Categories' properties. So, I canceled this solution.

I, also, have tried to use Inheritance to do so, as if I made `UIView` subclass and added all the properties that I want to. But in this case I **do** get my additional properties for all of my **custom class instances**, but I don't get them for any of the other UIView subclasses, like `UIImageView`.

I'm trying to figure it out but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I figured a solution to my problem. I'm not sure if it was the best one but it does work for me.

I've used a runtime feature of the Objective-C 2.0 which called: **Associated Objects**.

This feature gives me the ability to add custom properties to any class using Categories.

I found those resources helpful:

• http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

• http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxUjilPe5Do